# Can a booked transit passenger be denied to board on the plane in the transit airport?

Tags: transit, passenger-rights, royal-jordanian, amman

I have a confirmed booking from A to C via B.
In airport A I am checked-in and my luggage is tagged all the way to C. But I get only one boarding pass for the flight from A to B. The staff in airport A confirms that I will get my 2nd boarding pass in airport B at the gate of the flight B to C.

When I arrive to airport B I am not allowed to board on the aircraft flying to C as it is overbooked. 
Has the airline the right to do so? what are the passenger rights?

Because of missing flight B to C, I will miss a flight booked to depart from C to a final destination. So I book a new ticket from airport B to the final destination. As a result I lose the ticket C-final destination and incur additional cost to purchase ticket B-final destination. Can I claim the additional expenses/costs from the airline?

Comment: Are A-B, B-C, and C-D flights on the same ticket? From the tags on your question, I'm presuming B is Amman and the airline is Royal Jordanian, but you should include such details in the question itself.

Comment: We need to understand how you purchased this itinerary, and where A, B and C are. What "rights" you have depends on which country you're in.

Comment: Having a boarding pass does not guarantee you will be boarded in an oversold situation.

Comment: Please clarify what A,B,C and D are. Without them the answers would be probably  speculations.

Comment: **My Answer to  Roddy of the Frozen Peas:**
flights A-B and B-C are on the same ticket: A is Abu Dhabi, B is Amman and C is Beirut. the ticket is issued by Royal Jordanian. 
D is Rome and the ticket BEY-FCO (C-D) is issued by Alitalia.

Comment: **My Answer to Calchas:** I purchased my tickets online. My itinerary is clarified in my answer to  Roddy of the Frozen Peas, above.

Initially my ticket was a Qatar Airways ticket AUH-DOH-BEY. I had booked it to arrive in BEY 3 days prior my departure to FCO.
Due to the Qatar crisis, Qatar Airways replaced my ticket with a RJ ticket AUH-AMM-BEY that reaches BEY 5 hours prior to the departure of the AZ flight BEY-FCO.

Comment: **My answer to Tom:**
I understand that the airline can bump me off the flight Amman-Beirut, but why would they tag my luggage in AUH all the way to Beirut when they know that the AMM-BEY flight is overbooked and that they have no alternative flight on the same day?

Answer (score 3):

You never have to right to fly on a certain flight, even if you have a boarding pass.

The airline can always 'bump' you, for whatever reason they chose, or without giving a reason.

All you have is the right for *compensation*. The details depends on the country, and on the airline / the fine print in your ticket. At minimum, you'll get your money back; often enough *that's all you are legally entitled to get*. The airline might be nice and pay you a hotel, etc., or book you even on the competition so you make it to your destination; and typically they are, because they want to keep you a customer; but you don't have a *right* to any of that.